# Ord dont return correct number

Tags: php

I need to get char code.

But if try this
ä
It return 195 but it should return 228.

What i could see it could have somthing about the encodning?

Some one there know what happens?

Comment: how you come to know that it should return   228?

Comment: @Anant: 228 is the codepoint for UTF-8 (and for Latin1).